# Pumping Lemma For A CFL

Tags: pumping-lemma

I'm trying to prove that following language is not context free:

```
{a^n b^m a^n b^m : n,m >= 0}
```

I know that I need to use the pumping lemma. So I have to use w = uvxyz where |vy| > 0 and |xyz| > p (pumping length). I know that I need to show that when pumped a string for each case is outside the language.

I know the cases for when v^i or y^i is contains something and the other is empty but I don't know what to pick for my string.